# Will a mouse for XP and Vista work on Windows 7?

Tags: drivers, mouse

I'm looking to replace a mouse and found one that I really like on my other machine. It has drivers for Windows XP and Vista. Will it work okay on Windows 7?

Comment: The hardware of the mice remains the same even if it is windows 7..the drivers are for some extra functions that you can do with your mice like one from microsoft windows.

Answer (score 4):

Mice do not need drivers; all a mouse driver adds is functionality for extra buttons.

Vista drivers should work fine on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

In general, everything that works on Windows XP and Windows Vista will continue working on Windows 7.

It depends more on whether you're running the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows 7. If it's the 64-bit version, you will need 64-bit drivers. 32-bit versions will use the same 32-bit drivers.

But even if you can't find drivers, that won't keep your mouse from working. Windows has had built-in support for mice for quite a few versions now. Windows 2000 introduced native support for vertical scroll wheels, and up to 5 buttons are recognized right out of the box (left, right, middle, X button 1, X button 2).

The only thing you'll lose without drivers are the extra whiz-bang features of your mouse, the ones most people don't use anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason your mouse won't work in Windows 7.  If you provide a model number, we can tell you if there are specific drivers for it.  Even without drivers, all core functionality (left, right, wheel, etc...) should work fine.  For extra functionality, we'd need to know more info.